# How to stop the logic but run animation in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

Does any one know how I can have this happen in a windows phone 7 application (silverlight).

1. Start application
2. Draw a rectangle
3. Move rectangle using storyboard
4. Then show message when animation is done

I've looked all over and cant find much but if any of you can help ill be really thanksful im going to be puttng this out for free but ill credit you in the app

I am looking for c# code.

Comment: Can you show the code you have, or what you are having trouble with? SO is not a give me the code site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a rectangle and give it a Storyboard animation. Set this rectangle's visibility property to hidden (if you want it to appear at a specific time), then set it to visible whenever you want to show it. (You can use the [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property).

```
myRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
```

Storyboards have a [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event to which you can attach a handler.

Then you can play the storyboard animation using

```
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

In your `Completed` event's handler, show your message.

```
MessageBox.Show("Animation Completed");
```

Comment: I can't see how switching it from the default (Visibility.Visible) to Visibility.Hidden and back again will help? (Switching between two concrete states usually isn't considered animation...)

Comment: OP mentions 'Draw a Rectangle'. I don't know if (s)he meant just display it straight away, or draw it after some time. If the latter, then is should be hidden when the app first starts. I also don't have any reason to believe that the drawing of the rectangle is supposed to be animated (but if it is, that can also be done as part of the storyboard). The toggling of the visibilty isn't supposed to be an animation.

Comment: err ah lol sorry i seam to have put down what i am after a little bit strange to anyone that dose not know what i am on about (so me) i am wondering if there is a way to make the animation play though and show it doing so and then have the message show i dont know if i need to repost the question or not? But thanks guys

Comment: Seems like the same question, so I'll see if I can answer it here :) Lets break it down. First, you want to show the rectangle. Is this rectangle animated, or is it just displayed on screen when the user starts the app?

Comment: I create it in the code and then code the animation on it as well then i want to have a message box show after tha animation has played though

Comment: It's easier creating Storyboards in Blend. http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/ Storyboards have a 'completed' event. Inside this event, you can show your MessageBox.